# Mathematical induction proofs

Tags: math, proof, induction

For my theory of computation class, we are supposed to do some review/practice problems to work off the rust and make sure we are ready for the course. Some of the problems are induction proofs. I did this at one time, but apparently it has completely escaped me. I've watched a couple tutorials, but still can't do problem 'a'. If anyone can walk me through the first problem I'm pretty sure I could figure out the second one on my own. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: This is more appropriate for [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: The basic idea for problem a) is that you take the expression and substitute `n+1` in  place of `n`. You then fiddle with the expression until you get it into the form [`n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 + (n+1)^2`](http://goo.gl/CoZVgT). This is equal to [`(sum i = 1 to n of i^2) + (n+1)^2`](http://goo.gl/i3zx5R), which is equal to [`sum i = 1 to (n+1) of i^2`](http://goo.gl/Rpyqx7), proving the induction step holds.

Comment: The general idea is that you have to somehow express the value of a term for `n+1` using the value of the term `n`, and the obvious step between these steps as the appropriate function of `n+1`. (E.g. for a sum, the next step is adding `n+1` to the previous term. For a factorial, it's multiplying. For `2^n`, it's multiplication by 2.) Now, a snag in the works is that the approach for a) doesn't really seem to neatly transfer to an inequality such as is in b).

Comment: That said, you might be able to show that for all steps greater than a chosen starting value of `n`, the left side is multiplied by a greater number than the right side, which is always multiplied by `2`. (This is in fact pretty obvious for all `n` greater than 2, but you might have to be a little formal.)

Comment: Thanks for the help and I wasn't aware of the math.stackexcahnge. Sorry for the offtopic post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First verify it holds for n = 1.

Then assume it is true for n = x ( the sum of the first x squares ) and then try to compute the sum of the the first x + 1 squares. You know the result for the first x, you just add the last square to that sum. From there it should be easy.

And you posted on the wrong site.